# DB2 Select - Replace STATES with two character code

Tags: db2

I have a Users Table where it stores city, state and country along with other Users attributes.  The states are stored as California, Alabama and so forth.  Now I want to retrieve the user information for certain records but the state should get translated to two digit code.  Say 'California' should be 'CA'.  How should I go about doing this.

I was thinking to create a mapping table for state names with there abbreviation and then use some sort of replace function to do it.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You probably want to use a JOIN on another table, as bhamby shows below, rather than changing the data in the existing table. If you make *no* changes to the existing table, you can't possibly break any application code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably make a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE states (
    abrv CHAR(2),
    name VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO states VALUES
    ('CA', 'California'),
    ('AL', 'Alabama')
;
```

Then, you could just join to the table, to get the abbreviation:

```
SELECT 
    t.field1,
    t.field2
    s.abrv
FROM your_table t
JOIN states     s
  ON t.state = s.name
WHERE ....
```

Comment: I am going to try this.  Thanks bhamby and Mike for your response !!